# How to Manage CPU Utililization below 85% on Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008

We are facing a problem that **java.exe** process occupies complete **cpu utilization (100 %)**,
**OS:** Windows Server SP2 2007 Edition,
**Processor:** Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X7542 @ 2.67 Ghz 2.67 Ghz
**Memory (RAM):** 8.00 GB
System type: 32-bit Operating System
**Java Heap Memory:** 1 GB Allocated

Comment: i should not allow to go upto 100% CPU Utilization because it is the production Virtual Server, as a precaution i should find some sort of solution

Comment: Server Goes Down on Production Time Loss is like in half-crore

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for CPU usage going up to 100%.
Java is known for its thread and queuing process. So make it to process one by one.
Have a doubt whether your java.exe hits any db that is does it calls any Database to process.
If u could tell in detail I could help with more accurate solution

Comment: yes hims056/Karthik Swaminathan, j2ee framework on jboss server interacting with oracle 11g R2 DB as well as SQL SERVER 2005 SP3 DB